# How to scp from init.d

Tags: scp, init.d

I am trying to execute the following script from the /etc/init.d directory

```html
sshpass -p 'password' scp root@remote_IP:/file /copy/to/my/location
```

The script is running perfectly from the command line. I get an error of "Host key verification failed". When I use other commands e.g.

```html
echo "something" > /path/to/output/file.txt
```

the scripts is executed, so there is no problem with that. The problem is with the scp command and I guess it has to do with the key.

Can anyone give some advises on how to run scp from the /etc/init.d/ directory?

Thanks a lot is advance

Comment: In general, I recommend using -f to -p. With -p, you pass the password as a commandline argument, which is something that any user can read (via /proc/). With -f, the password is in a file, that can (and should) be inaccessible to other users, which is much more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`host key verification failed` means that your ssh config requires strict host key verification,  and that the key of the remote host does not match the one in your `known_hosts` file. 
If the init script is run as root, add the host key to `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` or (less secure) turn off host key verification for the remote host in `/root/.ssh/config`
See  https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh for more discussion.